# The ISR executed once even when the event not happened

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt, pic, atmega

I am using PIC24FJ128GA204 microcontroller in PIC24F Curiosity Development Board.
The ISR is executed at least once even when the event not happened.

Here is the code:

```
#include <xc.h>  
int Random_mode_condition=0;
void __attribute__((__interrupt__, __shadow__)) _INT1Interrupt(void) {
   Random_mode_condition = 44; 
    _INT1IF = 0;
}
void RC9_Switch_Config() {
    _TRISC9 = 1; // Switch input
   RPINR0bits.INT1R = 25;
    IFS1bits.INT1IF=0;//Clear the interrupt flag
    IPC5bits.INT1IP1=1;//Choose a priority
    INTCON2bits.INT1EP=0;//rising edge
    IEC1bits.INT1IE=1;//enable INT1 interrupt
}

int main() {
    LATC=0x0000;
    RC9_Switch_Config();
    while(1){
    if(Random_mode_condition==44){ TRISC=0x0000; LATC=0xffff;}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Random_mode_condition will equal 44 then the if statement will be executed.
Please help

Comment: What makes you certain that the event is not happening?

Also: might you need to make `Random_mode_condition` a `volatile int` ?

Comment: Any non-local variable modified inside an ISR must be declared `volatile`

Comment: Try to clear the interrupt flag right before enabling the interrupt.

Comment: Thanks for everyone, I cleared the interrupt flag right before enabling the interrupt and it works fine.